# Hosting a service with WCF from WSDL - SVCUtil generates verbose types for methods

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a WSDL file from a published ASMX web service. What I am after
is creating a mock service that mimics the real service for testing purposes.

From the WSDL, I used SvcUtil.exe to generate code. Apparently it also generates 
the server side interface.

Well the issue is that it generates very chunky interfaces. For example, a method
`int Add(int, int)` is showing up in the generated .cs file as `AddResponse Add(AddRequest)`. `AddRequest` and `AddResponse` have a `AddRequestBody` and `AddRequestResponse` and so on.

The issue is that, to implement, I need to create the body and response instances for each method, even when I just want to return a simple `int` result.

Why can't it generate the method signature properly? Is there a better way of generating WCF Server side interface/contracts from WSDL?

Answer (score 4):

The message structure you are describing is caused by two things:

- better interoperability across web service stacks and their programming models (RPC vs messaging);
- flexibility to accommodate new parameters into existing web services.

You are not [the first](http://www.designpatternsfor.net/default.aspx?pid=115) one to complain about it, or [the last](http://jim.webber.name/2004/08/19/6882d318-9742-4e15-8745-839aa566ccfb.aspx). It's a WSDL binding style commonly called the **document/literal wrapped pattern**. It produces document/literal web services and yet also supports an RPC programming style. It's very "[WS interoperability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-I_Basic_Profile) friendly", so to speak...

The WS-I Basic profile specifies that the `soap:body` must have only one child element and in this case it's a wrapper for the operation name that's being invoked. The parameters of the call are packed into only one element as a best practice since it's [more flexible to later changes](http://www.servicedesignpatterns.com/WebServiceEvolution/SingleMessageArgument). In case of WCF you usualy end up with [a MessageContract which has one MessageBodyMember](http://christopherdeweese.com/blog2/post/take-control-of-messages-in-wcf) which wraps all the parameters.

Basically, you are seeing the results of web service battles fought long time ago.

Here is some extra reading on the subject (and that's just the tip of the iceberg):

- [Which style of WSDL should I use?](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/)
- [RPC/Literal and Freedom of Choice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996466.aspx)
- [My Take on the Document/Literal 'Wrapped' Idiom](http://blog.paulevans.name/2010/08/my-take-on-documentliteral-wrapped.html)

Comment: Why in the world was I redirected to an iron table selling website with the "the first" link?

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat: I think some domains are no longer valid. The links are from 4 years ago