# Should I encapsulate the input / output in specific objects in SOAP Web service?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

In terms of good practices, in a SOAP web service, **I was told that every input and output should be encapsulated in a specific object**.

---

If we consider a basic `HelloWebService.java`, that would mean having two classes `HelloWebServiceInput.java` and `HelloWebServiceOutput.java`.

Which would give the following service:

```
@WebService
public class HelloWebService {
    @WebMethod
    public HelloWebServiceOutput sayHi(HelloWebServiceInput input) {
        HelloWebServiceOutput output = new HelloWebServiceOutput();
        output.setMessage("Hello there, " + input.getName() + "!");
        return output;
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class HelloWebServiceInput {
    private String name;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class HelloWebServiceOutput {
    private String message;
}
```

vs.

```
@WebService
public class HelloWebService {
    @WebMethod
    public String sayHi(String name) {
        return "Hello there, " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

Which simplifies a lot of things here and there...

So is there any particular reason why I shouldn't just respond with a simple `String` object?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370955/hosting-a-service-with-wcf-from-wsdl-svcutil-generates-verbose-types-for-metho/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950938/why-is-it-important-to-be-ws-i-basic-profile-compliant/. For your example it's overkill but SOAP services are mostly "enterprise level" entities where the input/output objects you mention give you advantages as the ones mentioned in the links